# How to add \= ("macron", "overbar") in an equation?

Tags: math-mode, equations, accents

I am trying the following code

```
        \begin{equation}
        \bm{F}=\bm{F}_{vol}\={\bm{F}}
    \end{equation}
```

But it's some errors. I think the error might be because I cannot use macron in math environment. how can I resolve this?

Comment: What is `\=` supposed to produce? Are you perhaps looking for `\bar`?

Comment: probably you want `\bar` or `\overline`

Comment: \={o}
ō
macron accent (a bar over the letter)

Comment: there is no overlap between diacritics for text and those for math, but for the ones common in math, there are parallel versions.  the macron equivalent for math is `\bar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general text accent commands uses symbol names: `\=` for macron `\"` for umlaut etc, and math accents (which are logically quite distinct) use words so `\bar` for an over bar accent, and `\ddot` for a double dot accent, etc. In the case of the bar  sometimes `\overline` works better (that is not built using the math accent primitives, but is simply a rule drawn over the expression, but unlike `\bar` which is a fixed character from the font, `\overline` extends as needed to cover the expression.